# How to change Pepper Robot's model for People Detection?

Tags: pepper

I'm using Pepper 1.8 with NaoQi 2.5.5.5. After try the basic awareness which provided by Softbank, I notice that Pepper cannot detect People who use mask. Can I change default model for People Detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option for that in the default people detection service. You will have implement your own pipeline, taking the video or 3D data, and applying your own algorithms to detect people differently.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to integrate  ([Pepper Face Mask Detection](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/blog/pepper-face-mask-detection)) it will detect the human whether with or without mask and you can customize according to your requirement for people detection.